# Writing A File Using Two String results in "0"

Tags: php, file, fwrite

Whenever I write onto a file, the result is

```
0
```

I don't know why. Here is my code.

```
                // Opening / Creating the main page's content
                $contents = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/contents/blog/mainpage");

                // Clean/Filter out special characters from the title's URL

                $bplink = str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST["bptitle"]); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
                $bplink = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $bplink); // Removes special chars.

                // Truncate content so that there will be a preview in the mainpage

                function truncate($str, $len) {
                    $tail = max(0, $len-10);
                    $trunk = substr($str, 0, $tail);
                    $trunk .= strrev(preg_replace('~^..+?[\s,:]\b|^...~', '...', strrev(substr($str, $tail, $len-$tail))));
                    return $trunk;
                }

                // This will be added in the mainpage

                $add_to_mainpage = '
                    <span class="bptitle"><a href="view.php?post='.$bplink.'">'.$_POST["bptitle"].'</a></span>
                    <hr>
                    <em class="bpauthor">By <a href="/about/'.$_SESSION["about_link"].'">'.$_SESSION["user"].'</a></em>
                    <br /><br />
                    <div class="content">
                        <p>
                            '.truncate($_POST["bpcontent"], 750).' <sup><a href="view.php?post='.$bplink.'">[READ MORE]</a></sup>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <br /><br /><br /><br />
                ';

                // Combine the old content with the new ones.

                $add_to_mainpage_final = $add_to_mainpage + $contents;

                $bpmp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/contents/blog/mainpage", "w+");
                fwrite($bpmp, $add_to_mainpage_final);
                fclose($bpmp);
```

I wanted to do something that looks like this:

Before:

```
// Old Content
    // Some more content, still old content
```

After the form submission:

```
// New Content
    // Some more new content
// Old Content
    // Some more content, still old content
```

I wanted that the new content will be on top of the old content. Can you tell me what's wrong and help me resolve it?

Comment: I have tried removing the `+ $contents` in the `$add_to_mainpage_final` variable, it works, but the previous content gets deleted.

Comment: have you checked whether the $contents is having something or not try with `var_dump($contents);` and check

Comment: @user790454, I found the error. I've listed an answer below. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found the error.

Replace:

```
$add_to_mainpage_final = $add_to_mainpage + $contents;
```

With:

```
$add_to_mainpage_final = $add_to_mainpage . $contents;
```

Forgot the combination of variables in PHP. My mind got stuck in JS. lol. Sorry. :)